Is it possible to design a circuit with an op-amp that always keeps the output voltage 1 volt higher than the input voltage?
Is it possible to design a circuit with an op-amp that always keeps the output voltage 1 volt higher than the input voltage? For example, if the input is 1V, the output should be 2V; if the input is 2V, the output should be 3V; and if the input is 4.5V, the output should be 5.5V.

Build an adder (aka summer). You'll need a stable 1V ref. This could be with diodes or an IR LED or a precise shunt reg (TL431 or TLV431) along with a resistive divider.

Yes. It is possible, given some assumptions about the min and max voltages it's expected to work over, the output current it has to drive, how fast the output follows input, how accurately it follows. Is that the only question your are asking?

Yes, it is possible.

Thank you for the solution

The answer given by Airpower will work. However, it requires a negative reference voltage. This alternative based upon a summing amplifier topology uses a positive voltage reference.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Voffset must be able to sink current, so a shunt regulator would work. The following uses a common 2.5 V shunt regulator instead of a 1 V reference (i.e. instead of equal to the amount by which the output voltage is supposed to be greater than the input). One could use, for example a TL431 for this purpose.

simulate this circuit
In this circuit, I picked an unregulated 5V supply to provide the current for the TL431 regulator. Any other value greater than 2.5 V could have been choses, with lower values requiring smaller resistors between the supply voltage and the TL431. However, in most cases, it is easiest to simply connect the TL431 to the positive supply rail of the op-amp through a resistor.

Use a Differential Amplifier. Here is a typical schematic. To get the -1V voltage source you can use a resistive divider from a voltage reference. If you do it this way, make sure the parallel resistor equivalent is equal to R1, then the math works out. 
